# Google Data Studio: How do you display the current date range?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a multi-page dashboard with a Data Range control which defaults to the "auto date range" (i.e. past seven days). I'd like to display those dates on the report, as the Data range control does not.

Answer (score -1):

Make a table with  Date as the dimension and allow 7 rows to be seen.  You can either use a general metric like pageviews in it, or no metric at all